# Combobox is resetting it's index when another user control is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have created a comboBox in my windows form that is auto filled by some database data. When i selected an index there are some label on the win form to capture other details of particular index. but the problem is when i click another control after making a selection , that combobox reset its value to one of my index.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: Can you provide a small piece of code that demonstrates the problem? It sounds like you might be handling an event and in that event you are affecting the selection of the combobox, but we would need to see some code to confirm.

Comment: Probably some LostFocus event processing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common causes for this:

- Does the comboBox have a Leave or LostFocus event that is causing the change?
- When you click the other control, is an event fired that will affect the comboBox, either directly or indirectly?